# How do i make the last widget always be at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

So i'm currently creating a detail page. Im trying to get a particular look and ive tried quite a few different approach such as using expanded Slivefill but im unable to get the desired look.

[image]

From the above image, From the left the first case is acceptable as there is a larger amount of text, the second image is where i have a problem. im trying to get it the very least fill to bottom of the screen.

the last image is the ideal condition i would like to achieve if there is a smaller amount of data.

if anybody could assist or point me to the right direction it would be highly appreciated

```
Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar(
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size(0, 1),
          child: Container(),
        ),
        pinned: false,
        expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
        centerTitle: true,
        flexibleSpace: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                background: Image.network(
                  loadedEvent.imageUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: -1,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                height: 20,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xfffffcf2),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                    top: Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            color: Color(0xfffffcf2),
            child: ListView(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              children: [
                Text(
                  loadedEvent.title,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 40,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    letterSpacing: 1.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  flex: 8,
                  child: RichText(
                    text: TextSpan(
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                      text: loadedEvent.description,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    child: Text(loadedEvent.date),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Are you trying to have a separate scrollable list inside sliver? Also does the bottom widget should be fixed at bottom?

Comment: Couple of questions:

1. You shouldn't use a SingleChildScrollView inside CustomSliver, SCSV uses it's own sliver internally so scrolling SCSV won't be synced to CustomScrollView's sliver, you should use NestedScrollVIew in that case.

2.  You are setting shrinkwrap to true, to prevent ListView from taking infinite size, in that case there is no point in using Flexible widget, as there won't be any extra space left anyway.

3. Why are you using SliverAppBar if it is always fixed at one position, this can be easily made without slivers and use a static container in place of AppBar?

Comment: @SankethB.K hey sorry for the late response, 
1) i'm relatively new to flutter and was trying to play around with it. i saw this youtube video on achieving the look of as the user scrolls down to read more of the text, the image will slowly fade away.
2) when i didnt have Flexible i kept getting renderoverflow issues, it was just a way for me to prevent that from every happening .
3) sliverappbar is being use as i had another thing i wanted to try out but have yet to implement as i had this issue, so i moved on until ive gotten some tips

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to achieve?

[image: Spongebob]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverAppBar(
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: const Size(0, 1),
                  child: Container(),
                ),
                pinned: false,
                expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
                centerTitle: true,
                flexibleSpace: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                        background: Image.network(
                          loadedEvent.imageUrl,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: -1,
                      left: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfffffcf2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                            top: Radius.circular(20),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  color: const Color(0xfffffcf2),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        loadedEvent.title,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 40,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          letterSpacing: 1.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      Flexible(
                        fit: FlexFit.tight,
                        flex: 8,
                        child: RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                            ),
                            text: loadedEvent.description,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0.0,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Text(
                loadedEvent.date,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: So i've tried your code, it's not exactly what i was trying to achieve. Your design sets it as static at the bottom. i'm trying to get it to be on the same scrollable widget but if its a short text it would be at the bottom of the page but if it's a long text then it would be below the end of the long text. if you get what i mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexible widget to the previous widget to set last widget to end of the screen. But you can't use scrollview otherwise ypu will get an error.